# How do I go about making a background navigation with spacing and gradients? I want the final product to look like this:

Tags: css

How should I go about making the below in CSS: Given that I am relatively new to coding I am not sure where to start with the background navigation as borders for all of the list elements are not just confined to the red line you see below.

Also, any advice on how to add the tick spacing inbetween would also be very helpful.

[image: Design of Navigation Bar I would like to have for website]

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

html:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

css:

```
#box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, #a30 50px)  
}
```

u can change '50px' above to control where gradient stop.

[learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)